# Insert records based on last entry of foreign table

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the following simple table relations:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
  ID                BIGSERIAL,
  TYPE              VARCHAR(24),
  TITLE             VARCHAR(128),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE EVENT (
  ID               BIGSERIAL,
  STATE            VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  DATETIME         TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL,
  PRODUCT_ID        BIGINT,
  FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_ID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

The "STATE" in Event, is converted from a Java Enum, can be: INITIALIZED, AVAILABLE, PROCESSED, etc.

I want to do the following: if the last event entry of the product has STATE 'PROCESSED', then create a new insert in the EVENT table with STATE 'AVAILABLE'. This must be for all products.

As you can see, the event table has a reference to product. I have looked at: [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/8702291#8702291)

But could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is inserted sequentially, I would be more inclined to use `id` for the comparison as in:

```
insert into event (state, datetime, product_id)
    select 'AVAILABLE', current_timestamp, product_id
    from event e
    where e.state = 'PROCESSED' and
          not exists (select e2.state
                      from event e2
                      where e2.product_id = e.product_id and
                            e2.id > e.id  -- you can use timestamp
                     );
```

What interests me more is that you have said that `state` is an `enum`.  Postgres *does* support [enumerated types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html), and you don't have one.  However, what you want to do is often handled using a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT (
  ID               BIGSERIAL,
  STATE            VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  DATETIME         TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL,
  PRODUCT_ID        BIGINT,
  FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_ID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT CHECK_EVENT_STATE CHECK (STATE IN ('INITIALIZED', 'AVAILABLE', 'PROCESSED'))
);
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted!! Data insertion is sequential, and what I meant with the Enum, is a Java Enum. I updated the post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO EVENT( STATE, DATETIME, PRODUCT_ID )
SELECT 'AVAILABLE', current_timestamp, product_id
FROM EVENT e
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 123
  AND e.STATE = 'PROCESSED'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 'anything' FROM event e1
     WHERE e1.PRODUCT_ID = e.PRODUCT_ID
       AND e1.DATETIME > e.DATETIME
);
```

---

If this comand is supposed to run in multithread/multiuser environment, then the whole transaction must consist of these four commands, otherwise duplicate records may appear:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

/* lock the parent record */
PERFORM id FROM PRODUCT WHERE id = 123 FOR UPDATE;

INSERT INTO EVENT( STATE, DATETIME, PRODUCT_ID )
    SELECT 'AVAILABLE', current_timestamp, product_id
    FROM EVENT e
    WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 123
      AND e.STATE = 'PROCESSED'
      AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 'anything' FROM event e1
         WHERE e1.PRODUCT_ID = e.PRODUCT_ID
           AND e1.DATETIME > e.DATETIME
    );

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The answer of Gordon Linoff was exactly what I wanted.